# Accessing a C double pointer array (**entries) in Swift 5

Tags: c, swift

I am trying to create a wrapper around a C library (libexif), so I can use it in Swift for reading metadata from Images.

I am quite new to C and Swift, but I have managed to get a bit of the way, however one problem stumps me.

One of the `structs` in libexif has a element called `**entries` which is of type `ExifEntry` (seen [here](https://github.com/libexif/libexif/blob/master/libexif/exif-content.h#L42)).

I have understood this to be a way to describe arrays in C with pointers.

However in Swift, this is inferred as `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<ExifEntry>?>!` type, indicating only one element.

I have found a few examples on how to turn arrays in Swift (`[String]`) to `**array` in C, but nothing the other way around and I cannot really seem to understand how to solve this.

Comment: In `C` `array` variable and `pointer`-to-the-first-element-of-memory-block  are pretty much the same thing. So, it's not "`indicating only one element`".

Comment: Hmm, I suppose so, I probably struggle with understanding this part of the typesystem.

Comment: It turned out to be quite easy:

      let entries = Array(
        UnsafeBufferPointer(
          start: rawEntries,
          count: Int(self.count)
        )
      )

Comment: StackOverflow rules allow (and even encourage) self-answering to your question when and if you found solution to your problem yourself(or your solution is better than other's). So feel welcome to put this as the answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be quite easy.

My function ended up like this:

```
  func entries(rawEntries: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<ExifEntry>?>, count Int) -> [UnsafeMutablePointer<ExifEntry>?] {
    if let rawEntries = self.entries {
      let entries = Array(
        UnsafeBufferPointer(
          start: rawEntries,
          count: count
        )
      )

      return entries
    }

    return []
  }
}
```

Where the key is the use of `UnsafeBufferPointer` which essentially takes the starting pointer of the C array and the number of objects.

In my case, the underlying struct in `libexif` which holds the pointer to entries, also holds the count.